# Getting details about the pinch gesture in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

In my project I have a pinch to resize option for the object that has been placed in scene view. But when someone pinch the screen to reduce or enlarge the actual size of the object I need to get that scale. I need to display the scale in which the object is being changed in the screen. How do I get the scale when the action is being performed?

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipinchgesturerecognizer/1622235-scale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your main ViewController Class for the ARSCNView

declare the label view, and the label itself at the top.

```
let scaleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, 70))
let labelView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: 300, height: 70))
```

Now within LoadView or ViewDidLoad you can set the attributes for the label such backgroundColor, textColor etc... and also add the view and label to sceneView.

```
// add your attributes for label,view

labelView.backgroundColor = .clear
scaleLabel.textColor = .white
scaleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

// add you views to sceneView

labelView.addSubview(scaleLabel)
sceneView.addSubview(labelView)
```

Lastly, with the pinch gesture function for scaling.. which should look something like this.

```
@objc func pinchGesture(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

 if nodeYouScale != nil {

   let action = SCNAction.scale(by: gesture.scale, duration: 0.1)
   nodeYouScale.runAction(action)
   gesture.scale = 1 

    // this part updates the label with the current scale factor 

 scaleLabel.text = "X: \(nodeYouScale.scale.x) Y: \(nodeYouScale.scale.y) Z:\(nodeYouScale.scale.z)"

  } else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that